# Change element text by getting value from AJAX respone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm not sure if my approach is correct, but my goal is to make a request and once a response is received all elements matching a certain classname are stored and then each element's text is changed to a result from the response.

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#calendarBtn").click(function() {
    $("#calendar").show();
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost:8000/calendar",
      success: function(result) {
        //Store elements
        var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("ei_Title");
        // Convert the NodeList to an Array
        var arr = jQuery.makeArray(elems);
        //iterate through each element
        $.each(arr, function(index, val) {
          //iterate through ajax response
          $.each(result, function(key, value) {
            console.log(key, value);
            var title = (result[key].title);
            //This is where I'm unsure as to how I set 
            the text of the element in "arr"
            to the "title"
            variable
          });
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="calendar_events">
        <p class="ce_title"></p>
        <div class="event_item">
          <div class="ei_Dot dot_active"></div>
          <div class="ei_Title"></div>
          <div class="ei_Copy"></div>
        </div>
```

Response:

```
{id: 6, title: "Walk the dog", date: "2018-12-05", assigned_to: "Sam", time: "11:00:00"}
assigned_to: "Sam"
date: "2018-12-05"
id: 6
time: "11:00:00"
title: "Walk the dog"
```

Comment: Post a sample of the Ajax response and a sample of the `ei_Title` markup...

Comment: I've edited the post.

Comment: How do you plan to "match" the response with each `ei_Title`?  Using the date? Not sure here if the whole approach is to reconsider... Are you using FullCalendar? If yes, have a look [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed).

Comment: I don't really have a plan. For now I just want whatever is in the response to show on the `div`

Comment: Try that: [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/WLTx8ZS7). But I'm sure it's not a good approach.

Comment: This works great for now. Thank you. If you want you can add it as the answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need only one loop to go through the Ajax response. Then, using the loop `index`, you can retreive the json objects and use the values to set the text of the "matching" elements.

```
success: function(result) {
  var elems = $(".ei_Title");

  //iterate through ajax response
  $.each(result, function(index, val) {

    // Set the title of each .ei_Title using the loop index.
    elems.eq(index).text(result[index].title);

  });
}
```

Note that the "match" simply is the order of both json objects and the elements.

If you use FullCalendar (which I think is the most popular calendar plugin), there is a most efficient way to feed it with a json. See its [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed).